# I am trying to run yargs command, and it is not working

Tags: node.js, yargs

**I am running:**

```
node app.js add
```

**And my code is:**

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adding command',
    handler:function(){
        console.log('Adding notes');
    },
})
```

But nothing printed on the console.

Comment: You never called parse or accessed argv...

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please explain to me why we need to call  `argv or parse` to print the handler execution? I am a newbie to `nodejs `

Comment: @læran91 because those are the things that trigger yargs actually executing the instructions you've provided.

Comment: argv is used to get the arguments passed to the node. js process when run in the command line. That is why you need it. ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comment above.

You need to either call [parse](http://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-parseargs-context-parsecallback) function or access [argv](http://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-argv) property

Try:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');

yargs
    .command({
        command:'add',
        describe:'Adding command',
        handler: argv => {
            console.log('Adding notes');
        }
    })
    .parse();
```

Or

```
const yargs = require('yargs');

const argv = yargs
    .command({
        command: 'add',
        describe: 'Adding command',
        handler: argv => {
            console.log('Adding notes');
        }
    })
    .argv;
```

`node index.js add`

Comment: can you please explain to me why we need to call `argv or parse` to print the handler execution? I mean what's happening behind the execution?

Comment: argv is setup as a javascript getter, which means accessing this property actually invokes a method.

Answer (score 10):

You have to provide the **yargs.parse(); or yargs.argv;** after defining all the commands.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adding command',
    handler:function(){
        console.log('Adding notes');
    },
});

yargs.parse();
//or
yargs.argv;
```

or

```
You can .argv or .parse() specify individually

    yargs.command({
        command:'add',
        describe:'Adding command',
        handler:function(){
            console.log('Adding notes');
        },
    }).parse() or .argv;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is okay if you have one command. But for multiple commands, do yargs.argv at last after defining all commands.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
 
const argv = yargs
    .command({
        command: 'add',
        describe: 'Adding command',
        handler: argv => {
            console.log('Adding notes');
        }
    }).argv;
```

Example solution:

```
const yargs = require('yargs')

//add command
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a new note',
    handler: ()=>{
        console.log("Adding a new note")
    }
})
//remove Command
yargs.command({
    command: 'remove',
    describe: "Remove a Note",
    handler: ()=>{
        console.log("removing note")
    }
})

yargs.parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue and find the solution with latest update of node. You need to change file extension from .js to .cjs and its working fine.