# yargs.command is not working (error msg: yargs.command is not a function)

Tags: node.js, yargs

I am trying to create yargs command, when I run the app I get an error.

When I run the following:

```
node app.js add
```

on my node.js code:

```
const yargs = require('yargs')
yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adding command',
    handler:function(){
        console.log('Adding notes')
    }
}).parse()

console.log('yargs.argv')
```

Error:

```
C:\node\notes-app\app.js:3
yargs.command({
      ^
**TypeError: yargs.command is not a function**
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\notes-app\app.js:3:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

---

- Yargs version:1.1.0
- node version: v14.16.0
- vs code version
- 1.55.2(user setup) OS:Window 10

---

Edit:
([I have already viewed this question but it didn't help because already added .parse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313940/i-am-trying-to-run-yargs-command-and-it-is-not-working))

Answer (score 2):

Try following lines.

```
const yargs = require('yargs')
const {hideBin} = require('yargs/helpers')
yargs(hideBin(process.argv)).command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Adding command',
    handler:function(){
        console.log('Adding notes')
    }
}).parse()
console.log('yargs.argv')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yargs 1.1.0 is a long time ago, 7 years infact. Back then they didn't have the `.command()` method.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs/v/1.1.0

The easiest solution is just to update. You should be able to go to atleast v14 or v15 with node v14.16.

If you don't want to you will need to add your own small command parser:

```js
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

if(argv._[0] === "add") {
   // ...
}
```