# Facing this error: TypeError: yargs.command is not a function

Tags: node.js, yargs

I am trying to run the `yargs.command` command. I tried running this code snippet :

```
import yargs from "yargs";
yargs.command({
  command: "list",
  describe: "List all commands",
  handler: function () {
    console.log("Listing all commands.");
  },
});

yargs.command({
  command: "read",
  describe: "Reading all commands",
  handler: function () {
    console.log("Reading all commands");
  },
});
```

And I got this error in the output:

```
TypeError: yargs.command is not a function
    at file:///media/Main-Volume/courses/Udemy%20courses/Node%20JS%20bootcamp/notes-app/app.js:23:7
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

After searching on the internet, I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313940/i-am-trying-to-run-yargs-command-and-it-is-not-working) and added this statement in my code at the end: `yargs.parse()`. But unfortunately, I am still getting the same output.

My OS: MX-Linux 21.

Node: 12.22.5.

yargs: 17.4.1.

vs code: 1.66.2.

Does anyone have any clue what went wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`yargs` is a function which returns the object with the `.command` property you want. From the README:

> ```js
> yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
>   .command('curl <url>', 'fetch the contents of the URL', () => {}, (argv) => {
>     console.info(argv)
>   })
>   .demandCommand(1)
>   .parse()
> ```

Your code should look something like this:

```js
import yargs from "yargs";
import {hideBin} from "yargs/helpers";

yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
    .command('list', 'List all commands', /*handler*/)
    .command(/*...*/)
    .parse();
```

Comment: So what should the code look like? I am not getting at all what you are trying to say. My apologies for that.

Comment: @lonewolf Is that more clear? Also `help` is the more common name, not 'list'

Comment: it is solved. Thanks.  I was doing that as part of an exercise in an online course. I was asked to include 'list' instead of 'help.'

Answer (score -3):

This is wrong:

```
yargs.command({
  command:
})
```

The below is right:

```
yargs({
  command:
})
```